# How to set size of button dynamically

Tags: android

I am currently developing a design for my android app in android studio 3. I need help in making the button size responsive. I need an xml or tag that allows the button to resize based on percentage of the width or height of the screen.

Comment: Try to use Constraints Layout, put your button inside constraint layout, set up based on percent width or height then you will find  it works like responsive layout for every device platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linear layouts:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- 30% height button -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Or try the [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#percent)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'

<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- 30% height button -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_heightPercent="30%" />

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is exactly what I needed but it needs to resize for the layout_width, I tried doing it like this android:layout_width="0dp" but it keeps giving me an error. I wonder why?

Comment: Set LinearLayout orientation to horizontal instead of vertical and change button height to wrap_content. Also, as you have already done, change button width to 0dp. If I have helped you please upvote this answer in order to help other users.

Comment: I also tried your 2nd suggestion, And I like it better. But I only have a problem. I cant seem to add a linear layout inside PercentFrameLayout. What do I have to do for that?

Answer (score 0):

two ways you can acheive:

```
1.Use constraint layout 
2.use SDP library to set height width value from library

  get sdp library from this link


 https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Main use of this library the values will change corresponding scren size
```